# Do not creating codefirst DB .net

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I deleted my database, and build `DbContext` again, but the database is not created. I tried migrations, but it always failed to build. Then I tried to put `-v` in Package Manager Console, and it returned this:

```
-v : The term '-v' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -v
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-v:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

DbContext:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class DrawContext : DbContext
{
    public DrawContext() : base("name=DrawDB_cs")
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

App.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DrawDB_cs" 
         connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=DrawDB;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is your build error?

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi writing only this: Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
Build started...
Build failed.

Comment: Check your error list and try to fix your errors. For add migration, project build should be succeed.